# Get all indexes where search item is in list, not only the first

Tags: list, search, tcl

Having a list to be searched

```
set haystack [list a b c d e e f e]
```

I want to find all Indexes where the searchstring is present in haystack:

```
set needle e
```

I have tried to use

```
set foundat [expr {[lsearch -all $haystack  $needle] >= 0}]
```

But I do not get the expected answer 4 5 7.

Comment: `set foundat [lsearch -all $haystack  $needle]` gives what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command:

```
set foundat [expr {[lsearch -all $haystack  $needle] >= 0}]
```

finds all the places that `$needle` is in `$haystack` and produces a list of all those places. That is a list of numbers. It then compares that list *as a string* with the value `0` except when the list has just one item in it, but the effect is the same since it basically ends up producing a true value for any result where a value is found. But really you just want:

```
set foundat [lsearch -all $haystack $needle]

set haveFoundAny [expr { [llength $foundat] != 0 }]
```

Nothing found? Empty list. Something found? Non-empty list.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you what you want:

```
lsearch -all $haystack $needle
```

What you wrote:

```
set foundat [expr {[lsearch -all $haystack  $needle] >= 0}]
```

Places in foundat if the search was found or not.

Answer (score 0):

List which you have mentioned

```
set haystack [list a b c d e e f e]

set needle e
```

This will give you what you want:

```
set e_index [lsearch -all $haystack $needle]

puts $e_index
```